# Function not called via javascript in href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onclick

I used a code that I found in the web and then changed a little thing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foodList = [];

    function addToFood (addFood) {
        alert(addFood);
        //foodList.push(addFood);
        //for (i = 0; i < foodList.length; i++) {
        //    var newFood = "<a href='#' onClick='removeRecord(" + i + ");'>X</a> " + foodList[i] + " <br>";
        //};
        //document.getElementById('foods').innerHTML += newFood;
    }
</script>
```

At this moment I only want to alert the parameter on addToFood. The function should be called:

```
echo "<a href='javascript:addToFood(". $zeile1['TITLE'] .");' class='band-head'>Add</a>";
```

this line shows how I add an `<a>` with the javascript in the href. The php render the right line but the addToFood is never called.

Have a look at the online Demo: http://anthraxx.sytes.net/ maybe it can help you more then me.
The error I get via Google Chrome: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` But just can't figure that unexpected identifier out.

Thanks

Comment: You have a JavaScript error. Look at the JavaScript, don't look at the PHP that generates the JavaScript. Figure out what the problem and what you need to change about the JS to fix it, *then* look at the PHP.

Comment: echo '<a href="javascript:addToFood('. $zeile1['TITLE'] .');" class="band-head">Add</a>';

replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the `$zeile1['TITLE']` inside a string, as such:

```
echo "<a href='javascript:addToFood(\"". $zeile1['TITLE'] ."\");' class='band-head'>Add</a>";
```

You can see that I added escaped quotes `\"` after the opening parenthesis, and before the ending one, in the JS-call.
Otherwise it will try to pass an variable to the function, instead of a string.

Why escaped? That is because you are echo:ing it with PHP. If I didn't escape the quote, the PHP would interpret it as I was ending the string, which is not what we want. I want to put the quotes in there as inline-code.

Answer (score 1):

Just scope your vaiable between `' '` or `" "` ,When you don't scope String's ,javascript read it like Var.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the $zeile1['TITLE'], thats true and you can do that by using following line -

```
    echo "<a href='javascript:addToFood(\"". $zeile1['TITLE'] ."\");' class='band-head'>Add</a>";
```

This is working.

Answer (score 1):

try  this

```
    echo '<a href="javascript:addToFood(\''.$zeile1['TITLE'].'\');" class="band-head">Add</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
echo "<a href='javascript:addToFood(". $zeile1['TITLE'] .");' class='band-head'>Add</a>";
```

With:

```
echo "<a href='javascript:addToFood(\"". $zeile1['TITLE'] ."\");' class='band-head'>Add</a>";
```